# to_json without header and index pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas DF

```
                                              data
day                                           2021-09-30
value1                                        730716000
value2                                        974689000
value3                                        375689000
value4                                        369077000
```

How can I convert this DF to json to be like:

```
{
    "day": "2021-09-30",
    "value1": 702228000,
    "value2": 924465000,
    "value3": 309753000,
    "value4": 306252
}
```

My best try was:

```
df.columns = range(df.shape[1])   # Delete headers
print(df.to_json(orient='index', indent=2))
```

But I got this output:

```
{
  "day":{
    "0":"2021-09-30"
  },
  "value1":{
    "0":"730716000"
  },
  "value2":{
    "0":"974689000"
  },
  "value3":{
    "0":"375689000"
  },
  "value4":{
    "0":"369077000"
  }
}
```

Bonus Doubt: Is it possible to parse only the values 1,2,3 and 4 of column data to int?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first approach is to `squeeze` your dataframe before use `to_json`

```
>>> print(df.squeeze().to_json(indent=4))
{
    "day":"2021-09-30",
    "value1":"730716000",
    "value2":"974689000",
    "value3":"375689000",
    "value4":"369077000"
}
```

**Note**: `squeeze` only works here because you have a `DataFrame` with a single column.

For the bonus, use a different strategy

```
import json

data = json.dumps({k: int(v) if v.isdigit() else v
                      for k, v in df.squeeze().to_dict().items()}, indent=2)
print(data)

# Output
{
  "day": "2021-09-30",
  "value1": 730716000,
  "value2": 974689000,
  "value3": 375689000,
  "value4": 369077000
}
```

Comment: For me squeeze doesn't do anything (pandas==1.5.2)

Comment: @craigB. You DV my answer and leave a comment, that is great. If `squeeze` doesn't do anything it's because you have not a `DataFrame` with a single column (like OP). If you have multiple columns, you should select only one. Please, if your case it's not the same than OP, remove your DV.

Comment: I actually upvoted but StackOverflow is being weird

Comment: If you edit your answer I can fix the vote issue

Comment: @craigB. I edited my answer with a side note for "squeeze". Thanks for your constructive comment.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be an `orient` value that produces what you want.

Use `to_dict()` to create a dictionary, then fix it up to what you want.

```
d = df.to_dict(orient = 'index')
for k, v in d.items():
    try:
        d[k] = int(v["0"])
    except ValueError:
        d[k] = v["0"]
print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
```

The `try/except` will convert the values to integers when possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can select column "data" and use `to_json` with the default (`orient='index'`):

```
out = df['data'].to_json(indent=2)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
{
  "day":"2021-09-30",
  "value1":"730716000",
  "value2":"974689000",
  "value3":"375689000",
  "value4":"369077000"
}
```

For the bonus question, you can use `to_dict` + dict comprehension:

```
out2 = {k: int(v) if k.startswith('value') else v for k,v in df['data'].to_dict().items()}
```

Output:

```
{'day': '2021-09-30',
 'value1': 730716000,
 'value2': 974689000,
 'value3': 375689000,
 'value4': 369077000}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import json 


json.dumps(df.to_dict()["data"])
```

dynamic way with out magic number or static strings

```
json.dumps(df.to_dict()[next(iter(df.columns))])
```

//output

```
{
"day": "2021-09-30",
"value1": 702228000,
"value2": 924465000,
"value3": 309753000,
"value4": 306252
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_dict` with `orient = records`:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({'day':['2021-09-30'], 'value1':[730716000]})
json.dumps(df.to_dict(orient='records')[0])
```

Comment: unfortunately I got locked in but this is an upvote

Answer (score 0):

The above methods didn't work for me in Python 3.11.1 / Pandas 1.5.2.

An inelegant solution:

```
            temp = '{'
            for index, row in df.iterrows():
                temp = temp + '\"'  + row['Column_1'] + '\":' + str(row['Column_2']) + ','
            json_string = temp[0:-1] + '}'
```